# WPF replacing a specific ListView item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Is there anyway of removing an item at a specific index in a listView and replacing that item with a new item at that specified index.

I can call `ListView.Items.RemoveAt(index);`

But I cant find a way to replace the item at that index.

Any help here would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use [insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydfzwwb7.aspx).

```
ListView.Items.RemoveAt(index);
ListView.Items.Insert(index, item);
```

Also untested but I don't see why `ListView.Items[index] = ...` shouldnt work

Comment: Insert works. Thanks! ListView.Items[index] = ... wasnt working for me I was getting out of bounds problems which didnt make sense

Comment: ah ok fair enough, it would probably fail if it was last element in the list.. (I'd have thought insert would at same point too)